# Strict aliasing warning, creating uint32_t reference to unsigned char array + offset

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, gcc-warning

With GNU GCC 4.7.0+ I got a few strict aliasing warnings, which I would like to resolve.

I have a payload (from hardware):

```
unsigned char payload[davidlt::PAYLOAD_SIZE];
```

I had this line:

```
*(uint32_t*)(payload + davidlt::DATA_OFFSET) = (pid & davidlt::PID_MASK) << davidlt::PID_SHIFT;
```

This creates a pointer to a specific location in payload and 4 bytes are interpreted as `uint32_t`. A new value `uint32_t` type is calculated and replaced in the payload.

I get:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

I was hoping to solve it by using `reinterpret_cast`, but I get the same warning.

```
*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(payload + davidlt::DATA_OFFSET) = (pid & davidlt::PID_MASK) << davidlt::PID_SHIFT;
```

As I understood you can convert whatever data to `char` or `unsigned char`, which is allowed, but that works only one way.

One solution would be to make a `union`. Aren't were any other way to create a reference of different type to `unsigned char` data?

Thanks!
david

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, viewing data as char or unsigned char is allowed, but not the reverse.

Instead you should use memcpy in this case. Your line takes a `pid` value, masks it, shifts it, and then inserts it into the payload. A direct translation of this would be:

```
unsigned char payload[davidlt::PAYLOAD_SIZE];

uint32_t payload_pid = (pid & davidlt::PID_MASK) << davidlt::PID_SHIFT;

std::memcpy(payload + davidlt::DATA_OFFSET, &payload_pid, sizeof payload_pid);
```

Another alternative would be to create your payload as a standard layout type with the appropriate size and members, and then to view it as an unsigned char array. Assuming you're in control of creating the payload:

```
struct Payload {
    ...
    uint32_t pid;
    ...
} payload;

payload.pid = (pid & davidlt::PID_MASK) << davidlt::PID_SHIFT;

static_assert(davidlt::PAYLOAD_SIZE == sizeof(Payload), "");

unsigned char (&payload_as_char)[davidlt::PAYLOAD_SIZE] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char (&)[davidlt::PAYLOAD_SIZE]>(&payload);
```

This isn't violating the strict aliasing rule because it's going the right direction now.

Answer (score 1):

The union would also be undefined behaviour. You can only use `char` in this respect- no other type is allowed, and that includes `unsigned char`.

Comment: Well, the most suggested solution is `union`. `union Payload { unsigned char bytes[32]; uint32_t half_words[8], uint64_t words[4]; };` But that would only work if data is aligned.

Comment: @davidlt, only reading from last written member of union has defined behavior; using union to "cast" types would still invoke undefined behavior (and work on most platforms, but that's in no way guaranteed).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create an array of `uint32_t` instead. This way you could access them as `uint32_t` but also as `unsigned char`: this does not violate the aliasing rules.

Comment: I get a data as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @davidlt with appropriate cast, you can get an `unsigned char` array in a declared `uint32_t` array.